# Tic Tac Toe code could probably be optimized more

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, tic-tac-toe

I recently got [some help from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58704185/) on my Tic-Tac-Toe code for the win conditions, but I think it could be optimized a little more. Any tips?

```
moves = [["1", "2", "3"],
         ["1", "2", "3"],
         ["1", "2", "3"]]
acc = 0
def win(letter):
  for i in range(3):
      if ((moves[i][0] == moves[i][1] == moves[i][2] == letter) or
          (moves[0][i] == moves[1][i] == moves[2][i] == letter)):
        print("~~~ " + letter + " WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
        quit()
  if (set(moves[i][i] for i in range(3)) == set([letter])):
      print("~~~ " + letter + " WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
      quit()
  if (set(moves[i][2-i] for i in range(3)) == set([letter])):
      print("~~~ " + letter + " WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
      quit()
  if (acc == 5):
      print("TIE YOU BOTH LOSE")
      quit()
def playerInput():
  global acc
  player1 = input("Where do you want to place your X, player 1? (row number, space, number)")
  moves[int(player1[0]) - 1][int(player1[2]) - 1] = "X"
  acc += 1
  win("X")
  player2 = input("Where do you want to place your O, player 2? (row number, space, number)")
  moves[int(player2[0]) - 1][int(player2[2]) - 1] = "O"
  boardDraw()
def boardDraw():
  print("1| "+moves[0][0]+" | "+moves[0][1]+" | "+moves[0][2]+" |")
  print(" |---+---+---|")
  print("2| "+moves[1][0]+" | "+moves[1][1]+" | "+moves[1][2]+" |")
  print(" |---+---+---|")
  print("3| "+moves[2][0]+" | "+moves[2][1]+" | "+moves[2][2]+" |")
  win("X")
  win("O")
  playerInput()
print("OK SO....\nPlayer 1 is X\nPlayer 2 is O\nGOOOOO!!")
boardDraw()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently, *"Tic-tac-toe"* game is gaining popularity on CR.
It may even deserve a separate playlist like *"Tic-tac-toe" Refactorings on various programming languages*.
You may find how other guys on CR already *succeeded* with different implementations (some on pure Python, some - involving `numpy` functionality).

But let's return to your current variation.

- `moves` list. It's better named as **`board`** (as a *game* field).
  Instead of typing all board items it could be easily initiated with `board = [['1','2','3'] for _ in range(3)]`
- `win` function. It sounds like *affirmative* but it's actually testing for a win.
  Thus a better name would be **`check_win`**
- `set(moves[i][i] for i in range(3)) == set([letter])` condition. Instead of generating 2 `set` objects - use a convenient `all` function:

  ```
  all(board[i][i] == letter for i in range(3))
  ```
- `for` loop (in `check_win` function) that checks for *crossed* row can be replaced with `any` call to serve a more wide consolidation.
- 2 statements:

  ```
  print("~~~ " + letter + " WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
  quit()
  ```

  are duplicated across 3 different conditions. That's an explicit case for *Consolidate conditional expression* technique - we'll combine the conditions that share the same "body" with logical operator.
  Eventually the optimized `check_win` function would look as:

  ```
  def check_win(letter):
      if any((board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] == letter) or
              (board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] == letter) for i in range(3)) \
              or all(board[i][i] == letter for i in range(3)) \
              or all(board[i][2 - i] == letter for i in range(3)):
          print(f"~~~ {letter} WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
          quit()
      if acc == 5:
          print("TIE YOU BOTH LOSE")
          quit()
  ```
- `playerInput` and `boardDraw` should be renamed to `player_input` and `board_draw` to follow naming conventions
- printing game's board in `board_draw` function looks really sad and painful.
  Python provides a good string formatting features.
  Just use them, as shown below:

  ```
  def board_draw():
      board_fmt = '''
  1| {} | {} | {} |
   |---+---+---|
  2| {} | {} | {} |
   |---+---+---|
  3| {} | {} | {} | 
      '''
      print(board_fmt.format(*[v for row in board for v in row]))

      check_win("X")
      check_win("O")
      player_input()
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Learned some things about python in the process :)

Comment: @James, welcome. It's good to be helpful for someone ...